# Не получается добавить AdView в Android studio приложение

Tags: java, android

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-19:19 to override.
```

Данная ошибка выскакивает при сборке проекта, когда загрузил AdView

Comment: Вы пробовали предложенное в сообщении об ошибке? Т.е. добавить `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` в `application` тэг в манифесте?

Comment: Да, попробовал, через alt+enter добавил строчку (xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"), получил ошибку (ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs), лог огромный, думаю нужно попробовать другую строчку

Comment: Привет. Ранее встречал подобное, мне помогла замена версии рекламы на 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь использовать **AndroidX** и старый вариант библиотек. У меня было подобное, пришлось выбирать, либо вернуться к `android.support` либо  поменять все библиотеки на `androidx`. Все же перешел на `androidx`, но пришлось долго менять библиотеки в `build.gradle(app)` ниже есть ссылка для замены библиотек. Но кроме этого пришлсь еще менять многие `view` в лаяутах. А в классах менять импорты.

Советую посмотреть [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

---

Ну и схожая проблема на EN.SO   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793345/android-material-and-appcompat-manifest-merger-failed/53202089

Comment: Migrating to AndroidX Помогло, еще прописал в gradle.properties, по инструкции. Потом заменил в MainActivity.class -- AppCompatActivity на Activity и ошибки не возникает)

Comment: Да, там очень много нужно изменить, и к сожалению некоторые ошибки студия не отображает, а можно увидеть только если открыть класс или xml файл.